# W3C validator issues: "end of document in prolog" and "Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference"

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Is anyone experiencing difficulties with [W3C HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)?

I've been using it for the past year without an issue, but today I started getting an error that looks like a validator issue:

> **Line 1, Column 1: end of document in prolog**
>   This error may appear when the validator receives an empty document. Please make sure that the document you are uploading is not empty, and report any discrepancy.

The thing is, I'm not even uploading, I'm using "Validate by Direct Input" and just pasting in the HTML... I've even tried the "Validate by File Upload" option, to see if anything's different, and that gives me something even worse:

> **Software error:**
>
> Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at /usr/local/validator/httpd/cgi-bin/check line 571. For help, please send mail to the webmaster ([no address given]), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

Is it broken? Or am I doing something very wrong?

Comment: Chances are you have stray characters from your editor not properly encoded. Make sure it's set to UTF-8.

Comment: I’ll follow up with the W3C systems team about this. I’ve seen other reports over the last couple days. Something exceptional is wrong in the backend that the W3C systems team needs to fix.

Comment: Note that you can use https://validator.w3.org/nu/ (the W3C HTML5 checker) directly instead, and you won’t run into this problem with that

Comment: @Rob That's what I thought at first, but then I pasted in one that I had just validated yesterday, to be sure, and I got the same error. I set it to UTF-8 in my meta tags, is that what you mean?
It does look like it's going through an update though, some things seem to be changing... :)

Comment: No. You're editor should have a setting for encoding in it.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thank you. I tried validator.w3.org/nu and it worked (it just gave me a bunch of warnings about declaring properties through CSS, instead of HTML... but I am designing for email).
Is the Validator doing some sort of integration with the HTML5 checker? I noticed that's on the Doctype dropdown list as experimental, and now it started redirecting me there, when I run a check. Maybe that's what's going on (software update)... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, forget all I said. I got the same error.

Comment: Yeah if you give `https://validator.w3.org/` a document with a `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype, it just redirects the request to `https://validator.w3.org/nu/`, which checks it and shows you the results itself

Comment: @Rob Oh, haha, well I guess we'll just have to wait it out until they're done updating the backend. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @sideshowbarker Oh, that's why. I'm doing XHTML 1.0 Transitional, but I just deleted the entire declaration and left <!DOCTYPE html> just for testing. That's when I was redirected. :)

Comment: @TiagoCotrim yep that’ll do it

Comment: OK, I found and fixed the validator server problem myself (since it’s off-hours for the systems team). But… it’s not clear to me what caused the problem—I only fixed the immediate symptom—so… it may occur again. But I’m going to be keeping an eye on it closely for the next few hours (until somebody on the W3C systems team more knowledgeable about this stuff gets back online for the day)